# After deploying meteor app to heroku missing fiber package

Tags: heroku, meteor, node-fibers

I deployed my Meteor app to heroku after adding a db etc. and when I try and access the app I get an error that says the server can't find a module called "Fibers". What does this mean? I never installed that module.

Answer (score 0):

Set your node version to 0.10.3.